# Docker compose frontend service call to backend service call gives net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have 2 containers in a docker compose network, her eis my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:

  backend:
    image: core:0.8
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  frontend:
    image: procedural:0.8
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 4200:80
```

Backend Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.7-amazoncorretto-17 AS MAVEN_BUILD 3.8.7-amazoncorretto-17
RUN mkdir -p /build/core
COPY pom.xml /build/core
WORKDIR /build/core/
RUN mvn dependency:resolve -Dmaven.test.skip=true -e
RUN mvn dependency:resolve-plugins -Dmaven.test.skip=true -e
COPY src/ /build/core/src/
RUN mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -e

FROM nginx:alpine

RUN apk add openjdk17https://apk.corretto.aws/amazoncorretto.rsa.pub
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/core/target/core.jar /app/core.jar

COPY nginx.conf.template nginx.conf.template
RUN mkdir /scripts
COPY entrypoint.sh /scripts/entrypoint.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/scripts/entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 8080 8080
EXPOSE 8084 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/scripts/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Backend entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
envsubst < /app/nginx.conf.template > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
nginx
java -Xmx350m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 \
    -Dspring.config.location=classpath:application.prod.yaml \
    -Dserver.port=8080 \
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
    -XX:+UseContainerSupport \
    -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=35.0 \
    -jar /app/core.jar
```

The backend nginx conf:

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        server_name backend; #also how its adressed in the frontend + docker container name
        listen       ${PORT} default_server;
        
        listen [::]:8080; #all ip v6
        listen 8080;

        #listen 443 ssl;

        absolute_redirect off;
        root      /www/data;

        location / {
            root      /www/data;
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            try_files /index.html /index.html;
            
            # for testing only
            if_modified_since off;
            add_header Last-Modified "";

            #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; #proxy pass remains

            location ~ \.css {
                add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
            }
            location ~ \.js {
                add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
            }
            
            #
            # Wide-open CORS config for nginx
            #
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                #
                # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                #
                # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }
            if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
            }
            if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

The frontend Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

#!/bin/sh

COPY ./.nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

## Remove default nginx index page
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# Copy static build files
COPY ./dist/procedural_mvp /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 4200 80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I can curl from the frontend container to the exact endpoint http://backend:8080/test/health

But when the Angular trys the exact same endpoint I get the net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error

What I tryed/checked so far:

- [x]  curl from frontend container to http://backend:8080/me/health is working and giving correct response
- [x]  nginx conf listens on 8080
- [x]  frontend container calls correct url
- [x]  controller endpoint is existing
- [x]  server_name of backend-nginx is backend
- [x]  cleared browser cache + tryed other browser
- [x]  containers are running and green
- [x]  containers are in the same docker network
- [x]  added http://frontend as allowed CORS origin to backend

I dont know whats causing this strange behaviour here.
Im accessing the Angular app through a browser ok, and I can see the frontend is loading nicely here I go over localhost:4200 which is mapped to 80 in the angular container and triggers a call within the docker network so http://backend:8080 should work or? (Port is exposed in Dockerfile + compose file, service name is right and so on)

Im on this for 2 days now and have no ideas anymore... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The Angular application runs in the end user's browser.  It does _not_ run in a container (it does not even necessarily run on the same computer) and it cannot see the Docker-network host names.

Comment: Hm ok, I have a knot in my brain at the moment: I understand that when I'm calling localhost:4200 (angular app) its in my browsers context, but the angular app is started with the compose file (as frontend service) I thought docker serves the angular app and when going through localhost:4200 Im coming into the docker network and there Im in the context of service names so I should use backend:8080 now instead of localhost:8080, if all of that is not the case: how can I access backend from the frontend then? only with localhost:8080?